# JSON summary column of a selected set of columns per group in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, jsonlite

I am trying to generate a JSON column of data summarizing certain columns per group in a data frame, but am finding it hard to get it in the format I want.

What I tried:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
mtcars <- mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 8), ]
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(x = toJSON(list(wt = wt, am = am, mpg = mpg), auto_unbox = FALSE)))
```

What I get:

```
  cyl                                                                     x
1   4         {"wt":[3.19,1.835,1.935],"am":[0,1,1],"mpg":[24.4,33.9,27.3]}
2   6                                    {"wt":[2.875],"am":[1],"mpg":[21]}
3   8 {"wt":[4.07,3.78,3.57,3.57],"am":[0,0,1,0],"mpg":[16.4,15.2,15,14.3]}
```

What I want:

```
  cyl                                                                                      x
1   4 [{"wt": 2.32, "am": 1, "mpg": 22.8}, {"wt": 3.19, "am": 0, "mpg": 24.4}, {...}, {...}]
2   6 [{....}, {....}]
3   8 [{....}, {....}, {....}]
```

Any idea on how to get there? Tried a few other things, but they all produce same json of arrays.

Comment: I get some errors with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `list` outside the `toJSON`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     group_by(cyl) %>% 
     summarise(x = list(toJSON(tibble(wt = wt, am = am, mpg = mpg), auto_unbox = FALSE)))
```

Comment: OMG. That is it! Was beating my head. I keep forgetting too that to get a summary value, you need to wrap under list like that. I believe you answered a different question with the same wrapping idea before.

Comment: @Gopala In some versions, it does work, but it is always good to wrap with `list` on a `summarise` output as it expects only a single element per group

Comment: To avoid spelling out column names for all columns, you can use across() - `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(x = list(toJSON(across())))`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
toJSON(data.frame(wt = wt, am = am, mpg = mpg), auto_unbox = FALSE)
```